Is it possible to read the annotation & PMI(General notes) details from Teamcenter Visualization Mockup(Vismockup) through VBA automation
I would like to read the "General note" details in "PMI user attributes" and reading annotation details in "Show PMI option" in Teamcenter visualization Mockup 14.3 version. I plan to use VBA or .NET for this automation.
Could somebody suggestion any syntax? Has anybody tried it already?
